# Can we automate the inbuilt camera functionality using Appium on ios device

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I am planning to automate my iOS native app using Appium. My app has the functionality of taking pictures. I researched little bit on this but couldn't find any help on iOS. 
I got some info from the NET to automate Android Camera, but my app supports only iOS. Can any one please help me on this?

Comment: As per I know yes you can, search on Google or YouTube by `xcuitest appium tutorial`, there are some useful tutorial.

Comment: Do you need to automate inbuilt camera app or your camera used by your app? If you want to automate inbuilt camera app you can use **com.apple.camera** as your bundle id. If you are using app's camera you can do it by clicking the elements.